# Javascript loop an array object and import into another file

Tags: javascript

First thing first, I don't know exactly how to describe this situation. But, I want to define an object to minimize the code. Here's the example:

```
let addtionalStatus = {
    ports: [
        1: {
            someKeys: "",
            someOtherKeys: ""
        },
        2: {
            someKeys: "",
            someOtherKeys: ""
        },
        3: {
            someKeys: "",
            someOtherKeys: ""
        }
        n: {
            someKeys: "",
            someOtherKeys: ""
        }
    ]
}
```

So, this is my code:

```
let additionalStatus = {
    ports: []
};

for(let i; i <= n; i++){
    additionalStatus.ports[i].someKeys = "";
    additionalStatus.ports[i].someOtherKeys = "";
}

export {additionalStatus};
```

the code above showing an error:

```
TypeError: additionalStatus.ports[i] is undefined
```

Comment: The data structure you are describing isn't valid.  Start there.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your ports object. if you want an array of object, it should be something like this: ports = [{1:{someKeys: "",someOtherKeys: ""}}]

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this instead.

```
let additionalStatus = {ports: []}
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  additionalStatus.ports.push({
    someKeys: "",
    someOtherKeys: ""
  });  
}
console.log(additionalStatus);    

// OUTPUT
{                                                
  ports: [                                       
    { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
    { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
    { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
    { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
    { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
    { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
    { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
    { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
    { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
    { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' }          
  ]                                              
}
```

I Will recommend you to define empty entries instead. Row data is easier to read at any time of the day.

```
let additionalStatus =  {                                                
      ports: [                                       
        { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
        { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
        { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
        { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
        { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
        { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
        { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
        { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
        { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },         
        { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' }          
      ]                                              
    }
```

Comment: This is more less code, thanks! But, ports will be start at 0 index instead of 1

Comment: @Fikry Arrays start at index 0, get used to it now and just do the conversion whenever necessary by subtracting 1.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I know... So, do I need to delete a 0 index because it's unnecessary, or I need to use index+1 every single time I wanna call it?

Comment: @Fikry don't worry about less code. Just define a bunch of empty entries. its easier to read raw data.

Comment: @Fikry use `addtionalStatus.ports[whatever - 1]` whenever necessary. Or just use `addtionalStatus.ports.map(port => /* use port here */)`

Comment: @AkshaydeepGiri that's the point... easier to read but harder to maintain. Imagine if there's a 500 raw and you need to update some key in every array. 'cause yep, in this situation I need to loop those keys for 500's times...

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code.

1. `additionalStatus.ports[i] is undefined` because you just define `i` in the loop, but don't assign value to it. Thats why `i` is `undefined`.
2. How you structure your data isn't correct. You can't define object with `key:value` pair directly into an `array`. Ex-

> ```
> // ITS NOT CORRECT
> const arr = [
>   1: { name: 'something' },
>   2: { name: 'anything' }
> ];
> ```

Now the question is how you should structure your data and loop through it ? You can follow as i mentioned bellow like this -

```
const additionalStatus = {
    ports: [
      { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' },
      { someKeys: '', someOtherKeys: '' }
    ]
}

for(let itemInArray of additionalStatus.ports) {
  console.log(itemInArray.someKeys);      // value of `someKeys`
  console.log(itemInArray.someOtherKeys); // value of `someOtherKeys`
}
```

**NOTE:**

To loop through an array: use `for-of`

To loop through an object: use `for-in`

Answer (score 0):

the error is because you haven't assign any value to array [i], it should assign 0 and n shouls be

```
additionalStatus.ports.length - 1
```

other wise it will give you error ***TypeError: additionalStatus.ports[i] is undefined***
*

check this

```
for(let i = 0; i < additionalStatus.ports.length - 1, i++ ) {

additionalStatus.ports[i].someKeys = "";
    additionalStatus.ports[i].someOtherKeys = "";
}
```

hope it will solve your issue

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
let additionalStatus = {
    ports: []
};

let ports = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    let obj = {
        someKeys: false,
        someOtherKeys: ''
    };
    ports.push(i);
    ports[i] = obj;
}

additionalStatus.ports = ports;

export { additionalStatus };
```

Comment: sort of... I already stuck in that situations for a couple hours before it's solved. Now I just realize that was a silliest question. Hope I can still see this question in a couple of years instead of delete it...

Comment: You know it's encouraged to answer your own question, you don't have to pretend to be someone else!